# Counting occurance of the word "the" giving me all different answers

Tags: perl

So I have a simple script to read in a text file from the command line, and I want to count the number of "the"s but I've been getting weird numbers.

```
    while(<>){
    $wordcount= split(/\bthe\b/, $_);}
    print "\"the\" occurs $wordcount times in $ARGV";
```

So using that I get 10 occurrences, but if I use  /\bthe\b/i  I get 12. /\Bthe\b/ gives me 6 I believe. There are 11 occurrences in my test txt. Am I just an idiot? Should $wordcount just be started at 1 or 0? Also is it bad practice to use split this way? The code works fine for actually counting the words, but not when counting an exact string. New to perl so any and all abuse is appreciated. Thanks

Edit: also I know it's not adding, but now I get that $wordcount is being treated more like an array, so it worked for a previous iteration, though it was definitely poor form.

Comment: You're overwriting `$wordcount` on each line. So you're only printing the number of occurrences on the last line. If you want the total, you should use `+=` instead of `=`.

Comment: All of them are wrong. Both because you're not adding (like Barmar said) and because `split` isn't any way to count the number of things that match a pattern (it will usually, but not always, be one too high).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`split` splits the string into a list based on the regex provided. Your count comes from the fact you've put `split` in scalar context. From [perldoc -f split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html):

```
 split   Splits the string EXPR into a list of strings and returns the
         list in list context, or the size of the list in scalar context.
```

Given the string "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog" I'd expect your `$wordcount` to be 2, which would be correct.

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
^^^============================^^^=========  -> two fields
```

However if you had "A bird and the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog" you'd end up with 3 which is not correct.

```
A bird and the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
===========^^^============================^^^========= -> three fields
```

First of all you absolutely would want `\b` as that matches a word boundary. `\B` matches things that aren't word boundaries so you'd be matching any word that contained "the" instead of the word "the".

Secondly you just want to count the occurrences - you do that by counting the matches of the entire string

```
$wordcount = () = $string =~ /\bthe\b/gi
```

`$wordcount` becomes the list in scalar context, `()` is a list you aren't actually capturing since you don't want the matches. `$string` is the string to match against. You're matching "the" at word boundaries and `gi` is the whole string (global), case insensitive.

Comment: didn't know I could use () as an array that way. Thanks for the informative answer

Comment: @D_C See [`perlsecret`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/perlsecret/lib/perlsecret.pod#Goatse) for more info.

Comment: @chrsblck the gotse made me laugh, but otherwise explained all the why's and how's I had. thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Use a regex in a list context to pull the count of matches:

```
my $wordcount = 0;

while (<>) {
    $wordcount += () = /\bthe\b/g;
}

print qq{"the" occurs $wordcount times in $ARGV\n};
```

Reference: [perlfaq4 - How can I count the number of occurrences of a substring within a string?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-can-I-count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-substring-within-a-string%3f)

Answer (score 1):

With the /i flag, 'The' would be included, but not without it.

\B is a *non*-word boundary, so would only find things like "clothe", and *not* "the".

Yes, it is bad practice to use split that way.  Properly, if you just want a count, do this:

```
$wordcount = () = split ...;
```

split in scalar context does something that seemed like a good idea originally, but doesn't seem so good anymore, so avoid it.  The above incantation calls it in list context but assigns the number of elements found to $wordcount.

But the elements produced by *splitting* on `the` aren't what you want; you want a count of times `the` was found.  So do (possibly with /ig instead of just /g):

```
$wordcount = () = /\bthe\b/g;
```

Note that you probably want +=, not =, to get a total for all lines.

Answer (score 0):

**sample.txt**

```
Ajith
kumar
Ajith
my name is Ajith and Ajith
lastname is kumar
```

**code**

```
use Data::Dumper;

print "Enter your string = ";
my $input = <>; ## User input
chomp $input; ## The chomp() function will remove (usually) any newline character from the end of a string

my %count;
open FILE, "<sample.txt" or die $!; ## To read the data from a file
my @data = <FILE>;

for my $d (@data) {
    my @array = split ('\s', $d); ##To split the more than one word in a line
    for my $a (@array) {
        $count{$a}++;     ## Counter
    }
}

print Dumper "Result: " . $count{$input};
```

The above code get the input vai command prompt, then search the word into the given text file "**sample.txt**", then display the output how many times it appears in the text file (sample.txt)

**Note**: User Input must be in "Case sensitive ".

**INTPUT from the USER**

```
Enter your string = Ajith
```

**OUTPUT**

```
$VAR1 = 'Result: 4';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print "Enter the string: ";
chomp($string = <>);
die "Error opening file" unless(open(fil,"filename.txt"));
my @file = <fil>;
my @mt;
foreach (@file){
@s = map split,$_;
push(@mt,@s);
}
$s = grep {m/$string/gi} @mt;
print "Total no., of $string is:: $s\n";
```

In this give the output what you expect.